# CXMLDocument parser

Tags: iphone

I am using CXMLDocument parser to parse an xml file in iphone... Its work great for me...

But i dont know how i parse the attribute name of the CXMLElement ? my sample xml is here

```
<thumbnail url="http://www.samplewebservice/image.gif"/>

<rating value="3" max="5"/>

<views value="1654"/>
```

I want to get url,value and max values from the xml file....

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use (resultElement is CXMLElement):

```
[resultElement attributeForName:@"url"] stringValue];
[resultElement attributeForName:@"value"] stringValue];
[resultElement attributeForName:@"max"] stringValue];
```

I hope this will help.